# php soap_client and socks proxy?

Tags: php, soap, proxy, soap-client, pear

been trying to use a locally created SOCKS proxy using ssh -D to proxy a soap call through a jump server.

MY web server doesn't have direct access to the devices I am attempting to use, so I figured I Could use an SSH proxy.

I can hit the wsdl from a web browser on the linux server, but curl fails.

I have verified using TCP Dump that the traffic is going out the network interface and not hitting the loopback for the proxy when trying to use the code.  IF I use the web browser it proxies through the loopback like expected.

```
    <?

 require_once 'SOAP/Client.php';

$username = "testuser";
$password = "testpass";
$hostname='10.200.96.86';
$soapoptions = array('namespace' => 'urn:iControl'); 
$wsdl_url ="https://$hostname/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi?WSDL=LocalLB.Pool";
$proxy_parms = array( 'user' => $username, 'pass' => $password);
$params = array(); 
$client = new SOAP_Client($wsdl_url, true, '', $proxy_parms );

$client->setOpt('curl', CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true)
$client->setOpt('curl', CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
$client->setOpt('curl', CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$client->setopt('curl', CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, "CURLPROXY_SOCKS5");
$client->setopt('curl', CURLOPT_PROXY, "localhost:1080"); // 1080 is your -D parameter

$response    = $client->call('get_list', $params, $soapoptions);

if (PEAR::isError($response)) {        
 print "an error occurred in the call " . $response;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

After I thought fixing the issue is described [here](http://www.livingwithphp.com/php-soap-client-socks-proxy/) I need to say, this works only for "Non-WSDL" Mode.

You have 2 possibilities for WSDL over Socks.

1. Load the WSDL by your own with curl (with SOCKS5 options) and use the ProxySoapClient class from the mentioned blog post. And initialize you client with:
   `new ProxySoapClient($wsdlContentFromCurl, $options);`

   But it may be that your WSDL have more dependencies witch are tried to fetch later on. And this won't work. So here is second approach:
2. Use ssh, polipo and the proxy option.

   Start the ssh `ssh -C2qTnN -D 8081 user@domain` this will create a SOCKS5 proxy on port 8081. Start polipo `polipo socksParentProxy=localhost:8081` this will create a WEB proxy on port 8123 to the SOCKS5 proxy on port 8081. (Normally the polipo is started by inet.d so you may stop this before running the local command)

Now use in PHP:

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    $theUrlToWSDL,
    [
        'proxy_host' => 'localhost',
        'proxy_port' => 8123,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer!

Answer (score -2):

After I thought fixing the issue is described here http://www.livingwithphp.com/php-soap-client-socks-proxy/ I need to say, this works only for "Non-WSDL" Mode.

You have 2 possibilities for WSDL over Socks.

1.) Load the WSDL by your own with curl (with SOCKS5 options) and use the ProxySoapClient class from the mentioned blog post. And initialize you client with: new ProxySoapClient($wsdlContentFromCurl, $options);

But it may be that your WSDL have more dependencies witch are tried to fetch later on. And this won't work. So here is second approach:

2.) Use ssh, [polipo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polipo) and the proxy option.

Start the ssh `ssh -C2qTnN -D 8081 user@domain` this will create a SOCKS5 proxy on port 8081.
Start polipo `polipo socksParentProxy=localhost:8081` this will create a WEB proxy on port 8123 to the SOCKS5 proxy on port 8081. (Normally the polipo is started by inet.d so you may stop this before running the local command)

Now use in PHP

```
$client = new SoapClient(
    $theUrlToWSDL,
    [
        'proxy_host' => 'localhost',
        'proxy_port' => 8123,
    ]
);
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)